# Inconsistent GTK theming since upgrade

Tags: gnome, themes

I've upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04.  I was using Gnome-Shell in 11.10 and still am on the current install.

I've noticed an inconsistency between the themes of applications - some appear black whilst others appear white, like this:
[image]
Nautilus is appearing in the white theme, whilst Movie Player is in black.

Adwaita is the theme that's selected for the GTK+ and Window themes.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Ambiance theme, the theme-ing of nautilus requires a separate `.css` file or specific theming.  Look at `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css` to see it.

You would need to copy that and correct the values for Adwaita.

Not all themes being completely converted for all the special cases with Gtk3 is probably why they are disabled by default.

**Edit**: I took a look at Adwaita and it's movie player that's not conforming.  I had it backwards, but the point remains the same.  You can add a `totem.css` to correct it.

Comment: I haven't got an apps/ directory inside Adwaita/gtk-3.0/.  I've created the directory and copied the file from the Ambiance theme, is it just a matter of changing the colours from the gtk-dark.css?

Comment: To me it looks like you need a file to specifically skin totem.  Like how some applications for some reason don't inherit gtk widget colors for specific widget names